Invalid `Podfile` file: unknown keyword: :privacy_file_aggregation_enabled
I'm building a react-native app with expo and have a whole generated ios folder with the Podfile. When trying to run pod install, I get the error [!] Invalid Podfile file: unknown keyword: :privacy_file_aggregation_enabled.. I couldn't find any helpful information online about this keyword. Is it safe to just comment the line out?

Have you looked into the solutions here? https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/20707

Were you able to resolve this? I'm getting this same issue @Cedric

the issue has been resolved after running npx expo install --fix 
